# Can I safely switch to Innodb file-per-table and delete ibdata1?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Can I safely switch to Innodb file-per-table and delete ibdata1?  Here's my plan of attack.  I have a recent backup of all data.

1. I added innodb_file_per_table=1 to /etc/my.cnf, and restarted
2. I ran ALTER tablename ENGINE=InnoDB; on each Innodb table

Next, I'd like to:

1. Stop MySQL
2. Delete ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1
3. Start MySQL

Will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html):

> With multiple tablespaces enabled, InnoDB stores each newly created
>   table in its own tbl_name.ibd file in the appropriate database
>   directory. Unlike the MyISAM storage engine, with its separate
>   tbl_name.MYD and tbl_name.MYI files for indexes and data, InnoDB
>   stores the data and the indexes together in a single .ibd file. The
>   tbl_name.frm file is still created as usual.
>
> If you remove the innodb_file_per_table line from my.cnf and restart
>   the server, InnoDB creates any new tables inside the shared tablespace
>   files.
>
> You can always access both tables in the system tablespace and tables
>   in their own tablespaces, regardless of the file-per-table setting.

The answer to your question: NO, you can't delete ibdata1, ib_logfile0 or ib_logfile1, because just enabling the option does NOT move your existing data.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that first.

Comment: Didn't work, it said the tables didn't exist.